# Extraer JSON de una página HTML

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de obtener el formato JSON sobre un HTML

Como respuesta a una petición obtengo lo siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hola mUndo</h1>
</body>
<script>
{
    "props":{
        "initialProps":
        { 
            "code":0,
            "verified":false
        }
    }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Ahora solo trato de obtener solo el JSON que se ve en esa página, estuve usando Explode, pero no logro acceder u obtener solo el Objeto.

Resultado esperado:

```
{
        "props":{
            "initialProps":
            { 
                "code":0,
                "verified":false
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.domdocument.php), como ya tienes el contenido, usa [loadHTML()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/domdocument.loadhtml.php) para cargarlo y manejar el HTML en forma muy similar a como lo haces con Javascript.

Luego busca el contenido del script con [getElementsByTagName](https://www.php.net/manual/es/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php), que devuelve un arreglo con todas las etiquetas encontradas ([Objeto nodeList](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.domnodelist.php)), en este, caso solo una y en la primera posición (cero).

Finalmente obtienes el contenido con la propiedad `nodeValue` y, ya de ahí, puedes usarlo a tu gusto, probablemente convertir a arreglo con `json_decode()` o lo que necesites.

```
$html = <<<EOT
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hola mUndo</h1>
</body>
<script>
{
    "props":{
        "initialProps":
        { 
            "code":0,
            "verified":false
        }
    }
}
</script>
</html>
EOT;

// Crear objeto
$dom = new DOMDocument();
// Cargar HTML
$dom->loadHTML($html);
// Obtener todas las etiquetas 'script'
$scripts = $dom->getElementsByTagName('script');
// Contenido de la única etiqueta en el documento
$json = $scripts[0]->nodeValue;
var_dump($json);
```

Resultado:

```
{
    "props":{
        "initialProps":
        { 
            "code":0,
            "verified":false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Funciona de maravilla, como hago para obtener un script en específico? si tiene un id?
<script id="__NEXT_DATA__">

Comment: Como te dije en la respuesta, el manejo es muy similar a como haces en Javascript. intenta con `getElementById()`